# Can I take flight from India to Poland on German blue card?

Tags: germany, poland, blue-card

I need to go to India urgently for some days and I live in Berlin, and hold a valid EU blue card. Have been working in Germany for 3+ years. My Niederlassungserlaubnis does not arrive yet, I applied a month ago.

All flight prices are skyrocketing at the moment from Frankfurt. There is a direct flight from our neighbor country Poland to New Delhi, which is much more convenient for me and the prices are quite OK.

For sure I can fly to New Delhi (India) from Poland, but not sure about re-entry. Will they allow my re-entry via Poland? or should I go book a return ticket only to a German city?

If I am not wrong, on Niederlassungserlaubnis, I can take a return flight to any EU Schengen nation, but I am not sure the same about the EU Blue Card.

Comment: Any Schengen residence permit allows you to enter the Schengen area through any country.  You can't use a German residence permit to _stay_ in other countries beyond 90 days in a 180-day period, but you can always transit through any Schengen country on your way to your place of residence.

Comment: Most residence permits issued by Schengen Countries have **residence permit** printed in english at the bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we need to establish whether the EU Blue Card is a *residence permit*. It is: the official [List of residence permits issued by member states](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/system/files/2022-08/handbook-annex_22_EN.pdf) includes the "EU Blue Card" issued by Germany:

[image]

Now head over to https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/ which is a friendly end user interface to Timatic, the service airlines use to decide whether you can board and see you are good to go:

[image]

Also

https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/blue-card/essential-information_en

> You can also travel through other EU countries on your way to the EU country that you live and work in.

Comment: There's an official list somewhere that enumerates all the documents that serve as a "residence permit" within the meaning of the Schengen Borders Code.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much for the clarifications and explanation.

Comment: @phoog thanks. Edited the answer to rely on that instead.