# Timatic for cruises?

Tags: visas, borders, cruising, timatic

According to Wikipedia (with emphasis added by me):

> Timatic is a database containing documentation requirements for passengers traveling internationally via **air**

Is there a similar system available for passengers of cruises or other types of non-air travel?

I am trying to determine whether I would need any visas for several countries, however when I enter my details and itinerary into https://skyteam.traveldoc.aero/ (from an [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/176513/40422) by @chx recently) it refers to being in Transit due to arriving and leaving on the same day, so I'm wanting to be sure that this would still apply if entering/departing by ship each day.  It also mostly offers airports as origin/destination.  I am also aware there are some places that require authorization when flying in, but not when arriving by ship or car - Canada for example.

Is a Timatic search valid for non-air travel, or is there an alternative that should be used instead?

I know I could ask here specifically for my itinerary, however I am interested in a general answer on whether there's already a database to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track that the documentation requirements **to enter** a country will be the same by cruise ship or air.

With the exception that some countries reduce entry requirements for people making a stop-off from a cruise ship - and Timatic won't know about that.

However the way you are entering your itinerary into Timatic is wrong.    Here, suppose A-b-C-D-e-F-A is your itinerary (lower case is where you plan to remain aboard the ship.)

You're telling Timatic that you have a single trip of multiple segments. **As such, Timatic is assuming you are remaining in *the airside transit area at the airport* between flights** at B, C, D, E etc. Which is not what you are doing at all.

When describing the cruise itinerary to Timatic, you should describe each segment, including ones where you do not plan to disembark (unless you have talked to the cruise line about that).

So in this case you'd ask Timatic about an A-B journey.  Then start over and ask about a B-C journey.  Then start over and ask it about a C-D journey.  Lather rinse repeat.

Comment: True enough, but such an enquiry will only disclose the entry requirements for the countries involved. It will not disclose what requirements might be imposed by the cruise ship company. In some or many cases, cruise companies require all passengers to be admissible into every destination where the ship is scheduled to make port, even if the passenger has no plans for a shoreside saunter. See, for example, [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174295/will-i-need-canada-visitor-visa-while-traveling-on-alaska-cruise/174296#174296).

Comment: @Anders There are indeed exceptions, but if Timatic is saying it's OK to enter country X by air, it's probably also OK to enter it by cruise ship.

Comment: Also cruise lines may have exceptions on visas. Some countries offers the 1 day pass (e.g. Oman). And Russia offered a special entry for cruises in St. Petersbourg (but only on official guided tours). Because cruise lines are usually repeating the same cruise many time per season, cruise sites may be more relevant for visa requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Harper-ReinstateMonica, you make a good point and I'll redo my search - The problem with the Timatic search is that it gives requirements for flying in, whereas arriving by car (or in my case cruise-ship) can sometimes have more relaxed or other requirements.  (However I do realise that it's a fairly minor problem)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi unfortunately my cruise agent has been fairly unhelpful and told me I'd have to find out for myself what the requirements are for me to enter each country.  She only has info for US citizens (>99.9% of her clients)

Comment: @Midavalo: contact your cruise line, and ask if there are special conditions for cruise passengers, if you need to have visa for all countries the ship dock, etc.. Then complement the information with Timatic. I check also foreign embassy websitse of the countries I go (the embassy in charge for my country, which sometime it is in other countries): if there are changes, they will usually write. Further the information is usually localized for your country citizens.